# Media queries with Sass won't compile

Tags: css, sass

I'm getting errors compiling my Sass files using media query mixins. I followed several tutorials, but it won't compile. I'm using `Sass 3.3.0.alpha.67 (Bleeding Edge)`.

**Here's my code**

```
/* Included at the end */
@mixin mobile-only {
    @media (max-width : 320px) {
        @content;
    }
}

/* Included where the rest of my sass is */
body { @include mobile-only { 
            display: none; 
    } 
}
```

I'm using Scout to compile and watch for changes. Is there anything else I need to be doing?

Comment: What error do you get?  It compiles fine with the current stable version.

Comment: error style.scss (Line 8: Invalid CSS after "...de mobile-only ": expected "}", was "{ ")
Sass::SyntaxError on line 8 of /Users/Dan/Websites/site_name/css/sass/pages/_home.scss: Invalid CSS after "...de mobile-only ": expected "}", was "{ "

Comment: Have you tried compiling it via command line (ie. without Scout)?  If it still doesn't work, you might need to consult the devs on that, since it is an alpha version.  That looks like the kind of error you'd get if you try to use `@content` aware mixins with a version before 3.2.

Comment: Yep. I was able to compile that with my current version of sass in the cmd line. I updated scout to 0.7.1 and it fixed the issue. Maybe my previous version of scout was looking for the older version of sass (pre version 3.2).

Comment: If you fixed the issue, please update the answer and mark it as answered @Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be an issue anymore. The *slightly* modified code is explained in this codepen http://codepen.io/danielcgold/pen/RRNrPQ.

```
@mixin start-desktop-size {
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    @content;
  }
}

body { 
  @include start-desktop-size { 
    background: red; 
  } 
}
```